# What are some first-order drag approximations for airframe/propwash interactions?

Tags: drag, airplane, propulsion

What are some first-order drag approximations for airframe/propwash interactions, both for dynamic flight and for static thrust, in a traditional tractor configuration?

Answer (score 1):

There is surprisingly little literature on that. [This answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14305/what-is-the-propeller-efficiency-%CE%BC-p-of-modern-propellers-for-light-sport-ai/36369#36369) by @xxavier lead me to a [very interesting paper](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~andrisan/Courses/AAE490A_S2010/Buffer/AIAA-46372-872.pdf) in which the drag of a Luscombe 8b with and without thrust was compared. A very thoughtful way was used to arrive at zero-thrust numbers, and the result showed that the additional drag from the propeller effects was about 30% of the total zero-lift drag without thrust.

In the paper, the prop efficiency is 81% while the overall efficiency drops to 62% due to slipstream losses.